# Getting Value at Selected Indices in C# ASP.net ListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, listboxitems

I am trying to get the value at selected indicies in a `ListBox` using ASP.net C#

```
MakeListBox.SelectionMode = ListSelectionMode.Multiple;
int [] indicies= MakeListBox.GetSelectedIndices();
```

I am going to dynamically building a select statement for a database query to an SQLDataSource. What I had hoped to be able to do was get all the selected indexes go through a loop to for the array that it returns and add each value at the specified index to a string.

I have looked through [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox.aspx) but can't find what is needed to do what I have talked about.

Basically I am looking for the opposite of the IndexOf command. Or a technique that would have the same results.

Comment: System.Windows.Forms != ASP.Net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clearly obvious when looking at the `ListBox` control properties, but this is the best way to do it:

```
foreach(ListItem li in MakeListBox.Items)
{
   if(li.Selected)
      {
         // Append to your string list
      }
}
```

Comment: That is wonderful. Thank you. Yeah, as  Java programmer having to switch over to C# for my job, the foreach loop was a bit new to me. Though Delegates still confuse me a bit.  Thanks again. I would upvote you if I could.

Comment: And SLaks' comment is important to keep in mind as you are learning C#.  The WinForms controls and ASP.NET controls may share names, but they can be very different in practice.  Whenever looking at MSDN, make sure you are looking at the correct article (WinForms vs ASP.NET, .NET version, etc.)  Good luck in your transition!